# How to map two different lists to one list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two lists of Generic types `A` and `B`:

```
public class A {
    int type;
    string params;
    bool isActive;
}

public class B {
    int type;
}
```

How could I map them into one list of type `A` where `B.type == A.type` (not `A.type == B.type`!!) using linq?

Instances of class `B` contain `int` values that can be deleted or added whereas instances of class `A` contain values from my db.

So for example:

```
A[0] = {1, "11", true}, A[1] = {2, "22", true}, A[2] = {3, "33", false}
```

and

```
B = {2, 3}
```

The desired result consists of `A[1]` and `A[2]`.

Comment: `B.type == A.type (not A.type == B.type !!)` what? those are the same

Comment: perhaps you could explain more what the result would be; say you have a list of 1xA and (separately) a list of 2xB. What is the result?

Comment: data from B can change so if A does not have the same type it shouldn't be added to new list. @Jonesopolis

Comment: Why not compile your data with an inner list? Like a 2D array but with lists or better yet dictionaries, they you can use B.Type as the key for the outer dictionary and the value would be a dictionary/list containing all your instances of A with the type related to the key of the item. Can provide code if you are interested in perusing that option

Comment: Could you also explain "map"? It might be helpful to provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you mean is "filter the items from the first list by checking a property against a second list" - in which case, I would suggest:

1. build an index from the second list:

   ```
   // create an index of the "type"s to look for
   var index = new HashSet<int>(bList.Select(x => x.type));
   ```
2. use this to filter the data

   ```
   // filter the primary list to values from the index
   var matches = aList.FindAll(x => index.Contains(x.type));
   ```

This will very efficiently give you a list of just the `A` data that has corresponding values in the `bList`.

Here it is runnable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public class A
    {
        public int type;
        public string @params;
        public bool isActive;
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int type;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        var aList = new List<A>
        {
            new A { type = 1, @params = "11", isActive = true },
            new A { type = 2, @params = "22", isActive = true },
            new A { type = 3, @params = "33", isActive = false },
        };
        var bList = new List<B>
        {
            new B { type = 2 },
            new B { type = 3 },
        };
        // create an index of the "type"s to look for
        var index = new HashSet<int>(bList.Select(x => x.type));

        // filter the primary list to values from the index
        var matches = aList.FindAll(x => index.Contains(x.type));

        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{match.type}, {match.@params}, {match.isActive}");
        }
    }
}
```

with output:

```
2, 22, True
3, 33, False
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to join both lists, so find all `A` which are in both lists?

```
var query = from a in aList
            join b in bList
            on a.type equals b.type
            select a;
List<A> resultList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: note that there are implications of using `join` depending on whether there are duplicated values in the second list - this is perfect if the values in the second list are unique. If the second list contains duplicates, a "contains" check may be preferable to a join.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for !?

```
var result = arrayA.Where(a => arrayB.Select(b => b.type).Contains(a.type)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that this is pretty inefficient - it does the `Select` separately for each element in `arrayA`, and uses exhaustive linear search to check the values. With some simple tweaks (see my answer) the same *idea* can be made much, much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two sequences, where both sequence have a value that should match, and you want to take zero or more properties form the first sequence and zero or more properties from the second sequence you use [Enumerable.Join.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.100).aspx)

The syntax seems a bit difficult, but if used more often you get accustomed to it.

Suppose in your example you have a sequence of A objects and a sequence of B objects:

```
IEnumerable<A> myAobjects = ...
IEnumerable<B> myBobjects = ...

// do the join:
myAObjects.Join(myBobjects,  // join the two sequences
myAobject => myAobject.type, // from the A sequence take property type
myBobject => myBobject.type, // from the B sequence also take property type
(myAobject, myBobject) =>    // whenever the values of these properties equal, take:
 ...);
```

The dots will be filed with what you want from the combination of a myAobject and a myBobject that have the same value for property type. Your question is simple: whenever a myAobject.type matches a myBobject.type, you want the complete myAObject. In that case the last part of the join is:

```
(myAobject, myBobject) => myAobject
```

If you wanted something else returned you would use something like:

```
(myAobject, myBobject) => new
{
    MyParams = myAobject.Params,
    MyOtherValue = myBObject.type,
}
```